# sync remote database (mysql) with sqlite database and vice versa

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite

In my android app I need to sync SQLite database with remote database (mysql) and vice versa....

the concept is something like when application launches application should sync database from remote database.. when I perform some action data should save into sqlite and then sync it to remote database..

Please guide how to perform this task.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

you can write an android [**service**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) which can be called when the applicaiton starts. this service will start [**syncronization**](http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/) in the background while the application can fetch data from the [**database**](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

**UPDATE**

here is a sample [tutorial](http://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/custom-content-provider-in-android/) for database.

Comment: Yes you are right... this is the way to do it.. But where I am confused is version issue of the database.  can you please provide some example.....

Comment: you wont be changing versions of database unless you change the schema of the db when upgrading your application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log all your statements in a table
2. Send them to the server via http
3. Execute statements there on the server (ensure that there is no duplication by giving statements a serial no)